# Scroll bar and other content disappear on adding a leaflet map to a webpage (weebly)

Tags: html, r, weebly, r-leaflet

I am trying to add a leaflet map to my website on weebly.

To do the same:

1. I published the leaflet map from R as a webpage (.html)
2. I added the html page on my git account [here](https://github.com/vjjan91/website/blob/master/html/WG_shapefile.html)
3. I used the embed code option in weebly to copy the code from the git page above, and everytime I do that, the scroll bar and other content from the page disappears.

How do I ensure that the scroll bar does not disappear? (This question was put on hold earlier, but there is more than enough information mentioned).

Any suggestions? (You can see the page [here](https://evolecol.weebly.com/current-research.html))

Comment: Have you looked at what CSS changes happen when leaflet is added?  Use developer tools in your browser.  Likely leaflet is overriding something, and you can fix it by making the original CSS have higher priority.

Comment: Not sure how to do that. Could you please help? @user2554330

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Chrome @user2554330

Comment: Have currently removed the leaflet map from my page. But can add it back if you would like?

Comment: I can't today, I only have a phone.

Comment: Please let me know when you try the same @user2554330